# Using r.mapcalculator and Python

Tags: python, grass-gis

I've been trying to write a script creating binary maps:

```
a=raw_input ("enter a threshold") 
b=float(a) 
grass.run_command('r.mapcalculator', formula="**'base_map'>=b**", outfile='map'+str(a), overwrite=True)
```

When I'm trying to execute it there's an error message :

```
Invalid map
Parse error
```

Obviously, when the relevant part of the code is changed (e.g. `formula="'base_map'>=**0.7**"`) everything is working fine. However, my goal was to write a script creating a map automatically when the "a" (the threshold) is provided.

Comment: I'm really not an expert, but is it possible that the formula is passed as such to Grass: "base_map >= b" (where you actually would like "base_map >= value_of_b"). Maybe you should somehow escape "b"? Just my 2 cents...

Comment: this is indeed a crucial question. how to "tell" grass to treat "b" as a value provided by the user (a=raw_input, b=float(a)) rather than a map (which obviously does not exist? as you can see I'm not an expert either

Comment: Have you already made som tries such as "base_map >= " b? I haven't ever found any extensive documentation on the Grass API for python, so my first guess would be to try a few options like this... But maybe someone more clever than me has a more clever idea!

Comment: This is a FAQ.  May I suggest printing out the value of `formula`?  Specifically, display the value of the expression `"**'base_map'>=b**"`.  I think the problem and its solution will then immediately be clear.

Answer (score 5):

The GRASS Python library uses the command grass.mapcalc, which is more along the lines of what you're looking for. It takes a string that is the same as the string you'd enter manually at the command line. Therefore if I'd enter the following string at the command line in GRASS:

```
r.mapcalc 'new_map = old_map - older_map * 32'
```

I could use the following line in Python to do the same thing:

```
import grass.script as grass
grass.mapcalc('new_map = old_map - older_map * 32')
```

So if you're wanting to construct a command for r.mapcalc in Python, try putting it together as a string. Here's an adapted version of your code:

```
a = raw_input("Enter a threshold: ") 
formula = 'map' + a + ' = base_map >= ' + a
grass.mapcalc(formula)
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the following works:

```
grass.mapcalc("$x=$A>=$b", x='output_map'+str(a), A='base_map', b=b)
```

in older versions of GRASS, the output will be saved as 'expression' so it is wise to copy and rename it before running the code again.