# Calling GRASS modules in pyQGIS?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, grass-gis, nameerror

I wish to use a Grass module (v.to.db) in QGis, without the grass toolbox.

I tried with the Python console, but to no avail :

- Using Sextante plugin but obviously it didn't know all the grass modules.

> from sextante.core.Sextante import Sextante
>
> Sextante.alghelp("grass:v.to.db")
>
> --> Algorithm not found

- An other test :

> grass.run_command("v.to.db", map='bl@PERMANENT', layer='2', option='start', units='meters', columns='X,Y,Z')
>
> -->Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in module
>
> NameError: name 'grass' is not defined

Do you know if there is an other way to use the grass module ?
I don't want to use it in the grass toolbox because I can select only one colums in "attribute field", and I would like to choose several columns.

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21867/r-mapcalculator-and-python-again shows how to import grass

Answer (score 3):

To use grass functions from a plugin or from the console, you must first import the grass module like this:

```python
import grass.script as grass
```

Forgetting the import will cause the NameError for `grass`.

Follow detailed instructions on [using grass from within python](http://code.google.com/p/postgis-grass-r-py/wiki/0003_01_PythonForGrassGis)

If you are running on windows and you get a Bad Handle error when you try to import grass, this is a result of an unresolved python bug that occurs on some window systems.  To work around the problem, put the code that imports and calls grass in a separate script.  Then, run this script as an independent process from within your plugin.

```python
callgrass.py:

if __name__ == '__main__':

import grass.script as grass
grass.run_command("v.to.db", map='bl@PERMANENT', layer='2', option='start', units='meters', columns='X,Y,Z')

print "Grass OUtput"

From Console/Plugin:

import subprocess

p1=subprocess.Popen(['callgrass.py', 'arg1', ...], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
p1.stdin.close()
ret= p1.communicate()[1] # grab grass output  
print ret
```

Good Luck!