# v.clean in QGIS Python console

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, pyqgis, geometry, topology

I have tried to use v.clean and v.clean.advanced (by GRASS GIS) within a script in QGIS, and was not able.

I followed instructions [here:](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40525/how-to-call-grass-modules-in-pyqgis), but was not able to do so. I got message: "No module named grass.script".

Any hint or reference to any source about how to do this?