# Create GRASS 7.6 environment in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-grass-plugin

I am working on PyQGIS in QGIS 3.10 (Windows).  My goal is to create a GRASS environment to be able to run modules like `r.in.gdal` among others. but i can't find the way to execute the modules. I have never worked with GRASS in PyQGIS modules.  I tried to use `processing.run` but it returns error since it can't find the module.

Comment: https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/GRASS_and_Python

Comment: Thank you.  but in pyqgis grass.script does not appear to import. that's precisely what I try to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this topic: [Calling GRASS modules in pyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40525/calling-grass-modules-in-pyqgis)

You can easily call GRASS modules into PyQGIS but I don't think you can call GRASS add-ons that are not already available in the QGIS processing toolbox.